# How to use "whether" and "while"?

Tags: grammar

Question:

"_____ the malfunctions of dishwasher are due to defects or low-quality material is still being investigated."

I don't know should I choose "Whether" or "While" to fit into the space. The answer is "While", but I don't see it's a perfect answer, and I don't understand why I cannot use whether. Is it because that both of two reasons (defects and low-quality material) are possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual answer is **whether**, it is defined as:

> **used to introduce the first of two or more alternative conditions**

([Source](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/whether))

In this sentence, you have two alternative conditions: defects and low quality of material

Therefore, whether would be appropriate. As a native speaker, while sounds incorrect and should not be used.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Comment: @Rila welcome, if i helped please press the tick next to my answer, it helps others with a similar question